# Mysql Counting rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table `msg`
 According to my SQL Query I require to select the `COUNT` to all `msg` acc to respective user.
Q1 - >

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM msg 
WHERE to = 2 
AND from IN(1,3,4) 
GROUP BY to
```

Q2->

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM msg 
WHERE `from` = 2 
AND `to` IN (1,3,4) 
GROUP BY from
```

How can i do this in 1 Query ?
(my user_id = 2)

```
msg_id|from|to|msg|
1       2    3 Hi
2       2    3 Hi
3       2    4 Hi
4       3    2 Hi
5       3    4 Hi
6       4    2 Hi
7       3    2 HiBye
8       1    2 Hi
9       2    4 Hi
10      3    2 Hi
```

Expected Output :

```
user_id|sent_c|got_c|
3        2        3 
4        2        1 
1        0        1
```

Comment: Sorry Edited Question @Strawberry

Comment: Yes @Strawberry typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways to skin this particular cat. Here's one...

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

  CREATE TABLE my_table
  (msg_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  ,msg_from INT NOT NULL
  ,msg_to INT NOT NULL
  ,msg VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
  );

  INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
  (1       ,2    ,3 ,'Hi'),
  (2       ,2    ,3 ,'Hi'),
  (3       ,2    ,4 ,'Hi'),
  (4       ,3    ,2 ,'Hi'),
  (5       ,3    ,4 ,'Hi'),
  (6       ,4    ,2 ,'Hi'),
  (7       ,3    ,2 ,'HiBye'),
  (8       ,1    ,2 ,'Hi'),
  (9       ,2    ,4 ,'Hi'),
  (10      ,3    ,2 ,'Hi');

  SELECT * FROM my_table;
  +--------+----------+--------+-------+
  | msg_id | msg_from | msg_to | msg   |
  +--------+----------+--------+-------+
  |      1 |        2 |      3 | Hi    |
  |      2 |        2 |      3 | Hi    |
  |      3 |        2 |      4 | Hi    |
  |      4 |        3 |      2 | Hi    |
  |      5 |        3 |      4 | Hi    |
  |      6 |        4 |      2 | Hi    |
  |      7 |        3 |      2 | HiBye |
  |      8 |        1 |      2 | Hi    |
  |      9 |        2 |      4 | Hi    |
  |     10 |        3 |      2 | Hi    |
  +--------+----------+--------+-------+
  10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

  SELECT user_id
       , SUM(status = 'sent') s
       , SUM(status = 'received') r
    FROM
       (  SELECT  msg_id,msg_to user_id,'sent' status FROM my_table WHERE msg_from = 2
          UNION
          SELECT  msg_id,msg_from,'received' FROM my_table WHERE msg_to = 2
       ) x
   WHERE user_id IN(1,3,4)
   GROUP
      BY user_id;

 +---------+------+------+
 | user_id | s    | r    |
 +---------+------+------+
 |       1 |    0 |    1 |
 |       3 |    2 |    3 |
 |       4 |    2 |    1 |
 +---------+------+------+
```